# Enable Packet Forwarding

Tags: fedora, sysctl

I am using Fedora 20 after running this command:

> "sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1"

it is giving this error:

> "sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/inet/ip/forwarding: No such file or
>   directory"

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to type:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

This works on fedora 21 for me

Comment: Works on fedora 25 as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: what for this sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why this would help. especially since you are trying to write to the /proc filesystem, which is usually offlimits in *nix

Answer (score 0):

```
su -      # sudo su - if Ubuntu
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This way even when you reboot the machine the setting will stay.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```